# Convert a row into multiple rows based on column value

Tags: teradatasql

I have a table with employees logging hours history, it has employee ID, Clock in time, Clock out time. I need to convert this row into multiple row for the number of hours clocked. If an employee clocked between 10:00am and 6:00pm i need to have 8 rows one for 10am,11am..until 5pm

Sample input

```
Id  start time  end time    work hours
1       10:00   18:00       8
2       09:00   18:00       9
```

Desired result for ID 1

```
Id  st_time work hours
1   10:00   1
1   11:00   1
1   12:00   1
1   13:00   1
1   14:00   1
1   15:00   1
1   16:00   1
1   17:00   1
1   18:00   1
```

Comment: It gets a little messy with `TIME` fields due to potential time zone offsets. If Start/End are `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (or just `TIMESTAMP` as long as you don't need to worry about daylight saving clock shifts) then it's fairly simple using Teradata's `EXPAND ON` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

While Teradata supports a `TIME` data type, using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP` (with time zone implied) is recommended. Here's an example using `TIMESTAMP` data type and `EXPAND ON`

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE example (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL, str_time TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL, end_time TIMESTAMP(0) NOT NULL) 
  PRIMARY INDEX(id) on commit preserve rows;
  
INSERT example VALUES(1,'2020-01-07 10:00:00','2020-01-07 18:00:00');
INSERT example VALUES(2,'2020-01-07 09:00:00','2020-01-07 18:00:00');
INSERT example VALUES(3,'2020-01-07 17:15:00','2020-01-08 03:45:00');

SELECT id, str_time, end_time, BEGIN(pd) AS bucket_str, END(pd) AS bucket_end,
  CAST((LEAST(END(pd),end_time) - GREATEST(BEGIN(pd),str_time) MINUTE) AS DECIMAL(4,2))/60 AS worked_hours
FROM
  (SELECT id, str_time, end_time, pd
    FROM example
    EXPAND ON PERIOD(str_time,end_time) pd
    BY ANCHOR PERIOD ANCHOR_HOUR -- Expand to multiple rows starting/ending on the hour
  ) AS xpand
  ORDER BY id, bucket_str;
```

The additional columns and ORDER BY were added just to help clarify the process, and could be omitted.